# Probability bound involving two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am reading a proof of a theorem which seems to use the following result while going from one step to the next step.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive random variables and let $\delta>0$, then $P(X+Y>\delta)\leq P(X>\delta/2)+P(Y>\delta/2)$.

Does this inequality hold in general?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When $X+Y>\delta$, at least one of them must be greater than $\delta/2$, since otherwise their sum would be at most $\delta$. Therefore, whenever $X+Y>\delta$, we must have $X>\delta/2$ or $Y>\delta/2$. Thus $P(X+Y>\delta) \leq P(X>\delta/2 \lor Y>\delta/2) \leq P(X>\delta/2)+P(Y>\delta/2)$. Note that this only applies when $\delta$, $X$, and $Y$ are all positive.