# How can one use Chernoff's inequality for non binomially distributed experiments by transforming them?

Tags: probability

Let  denote the number of pairs of  in a sequence of 1000 coin tosses where we also consider the pair of the last and the first coin toss (cyclic). I'm asked to use Chernoff's inequality (the one which is only applicable for bernoulli variables) so I can't do that directly since  is not distributed binomially. The tip is to split  into pairs of tosses  and +1 where one time  is even and the other time  is odd. Clearly, those two expirements are distributed binomially, but how can I use this fact to use Chernoff's inequality to estimate something of the form $(≥(1+)[])$ whereby I know that $=_{\text{ is even}}+_{\text{ is odd}}$ so $[]=[_{\text{ is even}}]+[_{\text{ is odd}}]$. Or can one use some other trick?

Comment: What are you actually trying to prove?  That there exists an exponentially small upper bound, or that the exponent in such a bound is given by a particular formula, or what?

Comment: Follow-on from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113317/is-this-experiment-describable-with-the-binomial-distribution

Comment: @kimchilover I'm just asked to use Chernoff's inequality on this experiment to estimate the above for $\delta = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=X_1+X_2$, where $X_1=\sum_{i=1}^{500} Z_{2i-1}Z_{2i}$ and $X_2=\sum_{i=1}^{500}Z_{2i}Z_{2i+1}$, $Z_i$ is an indicator of $H$ in the $i$-th toss, and $Z_{1001}\equiv Z_1$. Then
$$
\mu\equiv\mathsf{E}X_1=\mathsf{E}X_2=\frac{500}{4},
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{P}(X>(1+\delta)2\mu)\le \mathsf{P}(X_1>(1+\delta)\mu)+\mathsf{P}(X_2>(1+\delta)\mu)\le 2\left(\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\right)^{\mu}.
$$

Comment: What argumentation should one apply to explain the $\leq$ when splitting up the probabilities?

Comment: $\mathsf{P}(X+Y>a)\le \mathsf{P}(X>a/2)+\mathsf{P}(Y>a/2)$.

Comment: how is this rule called?

Comment: I have no idea. But it is really easy to see. Just draw the graph of $y=a-x$ and two lines parallel to the axis ($y=a/2$ and $x=a/2$).

Comment: A proof of this inequality can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3939067/545914).